# Convert J2EE 1.3 application into Java EE 5 or above

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-5

I maintain an old J2EE application that uses EJB's. What is involved in converting J2EE EJB's into Java EE EJB's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starter list:

1. Convert all your EJBs to the new 3.x standard.
2. Replace XML with annotations where possible.
3. Change to Java EE 6 JAR dependencies as needed.
4. Repackage EAR.